# Ruby undefined method while using PriorityQueue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm trying to use a priorityQueue from https://github.com/ldonnet/priority_queue on ruby, after installing it with `gem install priority_queue`, i'm having the error :

```
./example.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `push' for #<PriorityQueue:0x000000015ca200 @queues={}> (NoMethodError)
```

When trying to run an example of the README.md file :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'priority_queue'

q = PriorityQueue.new
q.push "node1", 0 
q.push "node2", 1

q.min #=> "node1"

q.decrease_priority("node2", -1)

q.pop_min #=> "node2"
q.min     #=> "node1"
```

ruby version : `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`

Thank you

Comment: If you just did a `gem install priority_queue` then you're getting this repo: https://github.com/ninjudd/priority_queue which doesn't have a `push` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem you linked do is (a fork of) the [`PriorityQueue`](https://rubygems.org/gems/PriorityQueue) gem, not the [`priority_queue`](https://rubygems.org/gems/priority_queue) gem. You need `gem install PriorityQueue`.

I realize that the repository you linked to *says* `gem install priority_queue` in the readme, but, that does not appear to be correct. The `priority_queue` gem is from [a different repository](https://github.com/ninjudd/priority_queue).